# Check if an array contains another array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-intersect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking if an array contains all elements of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867315/checking-if-an-array-contains-all-elements-of-another-array)

I have posted something like this to the Stackoverflow before, but the answers do not fully satisfy me. That's why I'm posting the question again, but changing the question all along.

Some people helped me to construct a function that checks if an `array($GroupOfEight[$i])` that is an element of a multidimensional `array($GroupOfEight)` equals another array($stackArray), disregarding the number ordering in the arrays.

However, what I need to check is whether the mentioned `array($stackArray)` contains any another `array($GroupOfEight[$i])` in the multidimensional `array($GroupOfEight)` or not, that means main `array($stackArray)` can consist more elements than `subarrays($GroupOfEight[$i])`.

Here is the one working code that I've gathered so far, but need to be modified to the version I want:

```
 <?php
    $GroupOfEight = array (
                          array(0,1,3,2,4,5,7,6),
                          array(4,5,6,7,15,12,13,14),
                          array(12,13,15,14,8,9,11,10),
                          array(2,6,14,10,3,7,15,11),
                          array(1,3,5,7,13,15,9,11),
                          array(0,4,12,8,1,5,13,9),
                          array(0,1,3,2,8,9,11,10)
                );


    $stackArray = array(0,4,12,1,9,8,5,13,9,2,5,2,10);
    /*$stackArray gets value with POST Method by URL parameter.
    This is just the example. As you see this array contains 
    $GroupOfEight[4], and also it contains many other numbers.*/


    /* The function given below checks if $stackArray equals any
    of the subarrays of $GroupOfEight. However, we want to check
    if $stackArray caontains any of the subarrays of function.
    If it does, function should return the index number, if it
    doesnt it should return -1.*/
    function searcheight($stackArray,$GroupOfEight){
        for($i=0; $i<count($GroupOfEight);$i++){


  $containsSearch = (count(array_intersect($stackArray,$GroupOfEight[$i])) == count($stackArray) && count(array_intersect($stackArray,$GroupOfEight[$i])) == count($GroupOfEight[$i]));
        if($containsSearch){
            return $i; //This specifies which index in GroupOfEight contains a matching array
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

// Calling the function that is given above.
echo searcheight($stackArray,$GroupOfEight);
?>
```

Any logical ideas or solutions will kindly be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected result ???

Comment: For the assumed $stackArray, it should give 4, which is the index of the contained subarray index number in $GroupOfEight

Comment: 4 is `array(1,3,5,7,13,15,9,11)` and `$stackArray = array(0,4,12,1,9,8,5,13,9,2,5,2,10);` .. can't you see 3 is missing in the list  ???

Comment: oh yes, but you got the idea. it contains a subarray and other elements. i gotta find which one it contains, or does it not.

Comment: Not quite yet .. what makes array 4 the most qualified

Comment: Even `array(0,4,12,8,1,5,13,9)` has more numbers in the search than number 4

Comment: it does not matter. when the page loads, user will enter some numbers. and first I will check if there is any contained 8 groups. if it does not i will check for 4 groups. and I will eliminate them. But I ask you about this function only. This will be very time saving for me.

Comment: so the `$stackArray` length has nothing to do with the result .. you are just checking in possibility of `16` `8` `4` etc ???

Comment: yes, stackArray length is maximum 16, does not matter if less. If less than 8, i will move to 4 group elimination, but that i can take care of, i guess.

Comment: I get you now .... 100% .. but you are also wrong .. the right answer is 5 .. because 4 only contains 4 possibly while 5 contains all the 8 .. count count it your self ...:)

Comment: yes, my mind is blown. sorry about that:) its good finally some one gets exactly what i ask for.

Comment: lol .. hold on am writing the script for you

Comment: thanks buddy, i've given it hours, but still nothing. i gotta do more practice about arrays.

Comment: You're the man! I can use this function for the four groups also i guess. Thanks. Very smooth answer. Understandable script. Great work.

Comment: where does that %4 term comes from anyway. I'm just wondering.

Comment: 16 , 8 , 4 .. they are all dividable by 4 ... its modules .. I figured i should just look for all values in the other array that is dividable by 4

Comment: great, now, one more thing. If they are more than 4 groups, what should i do. Use a for loop with this function? or this function can give multiple indexes? it seems like it can give multiple index'

Comment: What do you mean by if they are more than 4 groups

Comment: In the 4group elimination, i.e. $stackArray contains $GroupOfFour[5] and $GroupOfFour[2], does this function work?

Comment: It should work so far its dividable by 4 .. we would capture it

Comment: what if i make $GroupOfTwo and and change that 4 into 2, that probably changes the results, doesnt it ?

Comment: yes it does .. it looks for all intersection dividable by 2 instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
$GroupOfEight = array(
        array(0,1,3,2,4,5,7,6),
        array(4,5,6,7,15,12,13,14),
        array(12,13,15,14,8,9,11,10),
        array(2,6,14,10,3,7,15,11),
        array(1,3,5,7,13,15,9,11),
        array(0,4,12,8,1,5,13,9),
        array(0,1,3,2,8,9,11,10));

$stackArray = array(0,4,12,1,9,8,5,13,9,2,5,2,10);

function searcheight($stackArray, $GroupOfEight) {
    $list = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($GroupOfEight); $i ++) {
        $intercept = array_intersect($GroupOfEight[$i], $stackArray);
        $len = count($intercept);
        if ($len % 4 == 0) {
            $list[$i] = $len;
        }
    }
    arsort($list);
    if (empty($list))
        return - 1;
    return key($list);
}
echo searcheight($stackArray, $GroupOfEight);
```

Output

```
5
```

Comment: Baba, I've made modification functions and I've moved to 4 group elimination. Please revise this code and tell where i am wrong.
($GroupOfFour has 16mem)
function searchFourTerms($leftArray, $GroupOfFour) {
    $len4 = count($leftArray);
    $list4 = array();
    for($i4 = 0; $i4 < count($GroupOfFour); $i4 ++) {
        $intercept4 = array_intersect($GroupOfFour[$i4], $leftArray);
        $len4 = count($intercept4);
        if (count($intercept4) % 4 == 0) {
            $list4[$i4] = $len4;
        }
    }
    arsort($list4);
    if (empty($list4))
        return - 1;
    return key($list4);
}

Comment: I think I solved it, but still got some issues. Please move this to chat when you're here.

Comment: This answer is unexplained and the other answer (with 12 UVs) is 100% wrong.  This page is thus low-value to researchers.

Answer (score 9):

This one is fast:

```
function contains_array($array){
    foreach($array as $value){
        if(is_array($value)) {
          return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: always use block brackets {}, even for oneliners like yours `return true;`. It's good habit that pays of whenever you jump into languages using preprocessor and macros...

Comment: You can use a FOR loop, and return the counter if you need the position of the array. Or, instead of returning true, return the array key $array.

Comment: I dont think this one does exactly what i asked for, thanks though

Comment: I agree with @moz This is the correct answer to a different question.  I have no idea why this has so many UVs.