# PHP: Check if array contains another array values (in specific order)

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$haystack = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...);
$needle = array(3,4,5);
$bad_needle = array(3,5,4);
```

And I need to got *true* if I check if haystack contains a needle. But I also need *false* if I check if haystack contains bad_needle.
Tip without foreach for all haystacks and needles?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867315/checking-if-an-array-contains-all-elements-of-another-array does that answer your question?

Comment: This seems like homework. Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: **Tip:** Have a look under **Related** over to the right >>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$offset = array_search($needle[0], $haystack);
$slice  = array_slice($haystack, $offset, count($needle));
if ($slice === $needle) {
    // yes, contains needle
}
```

This fails if the values in `$haystack` are not unique though. In this case, I'd go with a nice loop:

```
$found  = false;
$j      = 0;
$length = count($needle);

foreach ($haystack as $i) {
    if ($i == $needle[$j]) {
        $j++;
    } else {
        $j = 0;
    }
    if ($j >= $length) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($found) {
    // yes, contains needle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump(strpos(implode(',', $haystack), implode(',', $needle)) !== false);

var_dump(strpos(implode(',', $haystack), implode(',', $bad_needle)) !== false);
```

A working array_slice() would still need a loop as far as I can work out:

```
foreach(array_keys($haystack, reset($needle)) as $offset) {
    if($needle == array_slice($haystack, $offset, count($needle))) {
        // yes, contains needle
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: And please, this should be faster than array_slice?

Comment: @Anette D.: I haven't timed it, but it doesn't fail like the array slice() example.

Comment: Array_slice works for your specific example, but not: `$haystack = array(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);`

Comment: Added working array_slice(). Shouldn't use $needle[0] cuz it could be any number or associative.